# Is just PIN and password without any hardware token considered to be 2FA?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

When using online internet banking, I have to use my 6 digit pin and a password to authenticate into the system.
There is no hardware token used in this example.
Is this considered as 2 Factor Authentication?

Comment: sorry.. i used a bad example. Should be Internet banking without using token

Comment: The more interesting question is, which banking site uses a PIN for online banking only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short: No

> Two-factor authentication refers specifically and exclusively to authentication mechanisms where the two authentication elements fall under different categories with respect to "something you have", "something you are", and "something you know".

This only uses "something you know"

[Full answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41939/two-step-vs-two-factor-authentication-is-there-a-difference)